# Browse folders functionality in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need my asp.net web app to enable users to select a folder from the file system and also from network, to copy the content files to another folder.

I am not going to use javascript activeX.

Please help as to how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.

[Here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/) is a tutorial on how to use it.

The control uses an HTML `input type="file"`, which uses the browser facilities for browsing files on the client machine (which, in turn, can use the facilities provided by the OS, such as a standard file browse dialog).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need to select folders and not files. Once the folder is selected, my code will copy the code from that folder to another one.

Comment: @S Mukherjee - This is not possible. Browsers do not allow such behaviour as it would pose a possible security issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can buy stuff, check out www.telerik.com, they got some very nice controls, one especially for you : File Explorer.